# TWA app can't run independently without running chrome browser firstly

Tags: trusted-web-activity, twa

Without running chrome browser firstly , TWA app will block at splash screen .
But after running browser firstly , TWA app runs normally.
Why?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? The Trusted Web Activity is provided by the browser, so it needs to run the browser first, but it should be mostly transparent to the user. The flow is: user clicks on the launcher icon -> the splash screen is shown -> the app is opened in full screen. Is something different happening for you? How do your expectations differ?

Comment: already solved , thanks